# ROS Answers SE migration: Optris package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to optris_drivers from ros.

I get this page but I don't know how to install it:
http://wiki.ros.org/optris_drivers

Can I have some help?

Best regard.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191708/optris-package/) by [bird12358](https://answers.ros.org/users/9116/bird12358/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to get the optris_drivers package working on Ubuntu 14.04 using ROS Indigo, but I had to make some changes to the repository. I have submitted a pull request, but the changes haven't been integrated into the trunk. In the meantime, my forked version can be found [here](https://github.com/steevo87/optris_drivers).

To install, change to your catkin source directory, probably with the following command if you installed ROS with default settings:

```
roscd
cd ../src/
```

Then clone the repo with:

```
git clone https://github.com/steevo87/optris_drivers.git
```

You should then be able to build it using the following command:

```
catkin_make optris_drivers
```

---

Originally posted by [Stephen Vidas](https://answers.ros.org/users/3606/stephen-vidas/) with karma: 131 on 2014-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on 2014-09-12**:
Did you test hydro branch of optris_drivers in ROS indigo? since hydro and indigo have very similar build infrastructures i think it would be compiled in ROS indigo either.

**Comment by [bird12358](https://answers.ros.org/users/9116/bird12358/) on 2014-10-05**:
I dowload the file with git but I get these errors: sudo /opt/ros/indigo/bin/catkin_make optris_drivers Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/catkin_make", line 13, in  from catkin.init_workspace import init_workspace

I don't really understand the error.

**Comment by [Stephen Vidas](https://answers.ros.org/users/3606/stephen-vidas/) on 2014-10-05**:
This appears to be a generic ROS error, and possibly nothing to do with the optris_drivers package. It seems similar to [this one](http://answers.ros.org/question/51325/catkin_make-error-in-groovy/). Was there any additional information for that error?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-12-29**:
I suggest you go through the [ROS Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) for how to build ROS packages.